# Не удалось установить пакет «Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.3»

Tags: c#, nuget

Не удалось установить пакет «Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.3». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета.

Почему это выводит, и как мне установить этот пакет?

Comment: Создайте проект под .NET 5 или 6, тогда сможете. Framework 4.x устарел и несовместим с EF Core.

Comment: net core вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 тоже уже староват, но да, мыслите правильно.

Comment: Можно как-то на .net перенести все с этого проекта?

Comment: Наверное как-то можно. Я не переносил.

Comment: Если проект большой, то советую сразу на .NET 6, он актуальный LTS.